# Why Can I Run Ubuntu but Not Kali in WSL with Hyper-V Disabled?

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux, hyper-v

I'm using WSL2 and have Hyper-V disabled so that I can run VMWare; I'm able to still run Ubuntu 20.04 then, but not Kali? Both have been installed via the Windows Store.

Kali coughs up this error when trying to access it:

> Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
> For information please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2-install

> [process exited with code 4294967295]

If I Enable Hyper-V, then I can run both Ubuntu and Kali, but not VMWare.

Any idea why Kali won't run with HV disabled, but Ubuntu does?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out the reason for me was that Ubuntu was set to run in WSL1 while Kali was set to run in WSL2.

For whatever reason, WSL2 OS's can't run when you have `/set hypervisorlaunchtype Auto` in your BCD (enabling Hyper-V), but WSL1 OS's can ...

I *could* downgrade them both to WSL1:

`wsl --set-version <distro name> 1`

But I prefer not to. I actually upgraded Ubuntu to WSL2 and now it also gives the same error, but I suppose since I don't rely on using them daily I'll just keep them at WSL2, (annoyingly rebooting and toggling that BCD flag as needed) and hope VMWare finally gets their ish together so they can all live happily side-by-side.

Comment: You can solve the Hyper-V problem but updating Windows and VMWare to the current version. VMWare already happily lives side-by-side with Hyper-V you’re just on an unsupported version of Windows (1909).